# How to use readline in NodeJs on an event (wait stream close)

Tags: node.js, async-await, readline

I'm creating a bot that when it receives a message begins to read a text file and responds to the message with the contents of the file.

Unfortunately, I can't get out of this asynchronous hell and I only get errors, undefined or promise

The last experiment was this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

// bot.listen("message").reply(responseText())

function readFile(file) {
    var text = '';
        var readInterface = readline.createInterface({
            input: fs.createReadStream(file),
            terminal: false
        });

        readInterface.on('line', function(line) {
            linea = line.trim();
            console.log(linea);
            text += linea;
        }).on('close', function() {
            return text;
        });
    });
}

async function responseText() {
    var content = await readFile("file.txt");
    content.then(function(data) {
        return data;
    })
}
```

What I would like to get then is delay the response until I get the contents of the file. 
I know that node is based on async but I can't figure out how to handle it!

Thanks all

Comment: If you want to read a file, you don't need to use `readline` and concatenate the file, line by line, into a string. Just use [`fs.readFile()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback), as in `fs.readFile("file.txt", "utf8", (err, contents) => { console.log(contents); });`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `async-await` need to create a promise and return it.

```
function readFile(file) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        try {
            var text = '';
            var readInterface = readline.createInterface({
                input: fs.createReadStream(file),
                terminal: false
            });

            readInterface
                .on('line', function (line) {
                    linea = line.trim();
                    text += linea;
                })
                .on('close', function () {
                    res(text);
                });
        } catch(err){
            rej(err)
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using express.js or any framework built on top of it, you can simply pipe the readstream to the response since express's responses are streams to begin with:

```
const es = require('event-stream')
...
let getFileStream = path => (
fs.createReadStream(path)
.pipe(es.split())
.pipe(es.map(function (data, cb) { 
      cb(null
        , inspect(JSON.parse(data)))  
    }))
);

router.get('/message', function (req, res, next) {
   let file$ = getFileStream(yourFilePath)
       file$.on('error', next).pipe(res)

})
```

If you need to transform the file content, you can use a [transform stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_duplex_and_transform_streams) or as shown in the example above, a synchronous event-stream mapping. The idea is to always play around with the file content at stream level to avoid having to load the entire file content in memory.

You don't really want to buffer the whole file content in memory. It can quickly become a problem with huge files on a busy day. what you need is to pipe the file stream directly to the browser. Same principle applies for any kind of consumer.

Of course, if the mechanism is all internal, you should only pass the file path along or the actual stream until you need to actually open the file and do something with the content. In this case, you go back to your stream toolbox, whether it be the native node.js stream API implementation, the event-stream package or some kind of observable library like rxjs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in an app that watches a directory for new files, reads the file(s) and returns derived data based on the file content. My Reader function is based on this [async example](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line) from the nodejs docs. I return `options`, which contains the context, only after the file is read completely.

```
const { createReadStream } = require('fs')
const { createInterface } = require('readline')
const { once } = require('events')

// Reader.js
async function Reader (options) {
  let { file, cb } = options
  let fileStream = createReadStream(file)

  const readInterface = createInterface({
    input: fileStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  })

  readInterface.on('line', (line) => {
    cb(line)
  })

  await once(readInterface, 'close')
  return options
}
module.exports = Reader
```

I then have a file which imports my Reader and defines how to use it. I define a callback function to pass to the `line` event listener. I bind the callback to the options object that I pass to my Reader function. In the 
 `readFile` function I make sure to `return` the call to Reader, which is a Promise.

```
/**
 * @desc callback to instruct what to do with each line read
 *
 * @param {*} line
 */
const readFileLine = function (line) {
  linea = line.trim();
  console.log(linea);
  text += linea;
  this.context += linea
}

/**
 * @desc once the added file is ready to be processed read file line by line
 * @listens {Event} listens for `process` event
*/
const readFile = (options) => {
  return Reader(options)
}

/**
 * @desc Call the file reader and do what you need with the reponse
 * 
*/
const getResponseFromFiles = (file) => {
  const opts = {}
  opts.cb = readFileLine.bind(opts)
  opts.context = ''
  opts.file = file
  readFile(opts)
  .then(data => {
      process.exitCode = 0
      console.log(data)
      return data
    })
    .catch(err => {
      process.exitCode = 1
      console.log(err.message)
    })
}
```